# asking for confirmation when using ssh scp

Tags: ssh

I need to do the following in linux command-line:

```
ssh -o LogLevel=Error remote "scp f.log myhost:~/f.log'
```

and it always failed.

After I ssh to the `remote` machine, I found when I did the following

```
$ scp f.log myhost:~/f.log 
The authenticity of host 'myhost(xxx.xx.xxx.xx)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is xx:xx:xx.....
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

How can I disable this second checking?

Comment: this should happen exactly once per server, and after initially confirming the host key, it should happen no more on subsequent connections.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `StrictHostKeyChecking` option to **no**.

So try `ssh -o LogLevel=Error remote "scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no f.log myhost:~/f.log'`

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to create SSH keys and use them. That second checking should only happen once as far as I know (it adds a host RSA key to a `known_hosts` file if you input `yes`).

Have you tried to get help at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)?